# Filter the value in object when the keys differ in an array

Tags: javascript

Response from get request :

```
[
    {
    id: 234,
    resturant_name : "dish",
    cusions : {1:"italian", 2 : "indian", 3: "foo"},
    address : NYI

    },
    {
        id: 235,
        resturant_name : "kebab",
        cusions : {1:"china", 2 : "indian", 3: "american"},
        address : NYI

    },
    {
        id: 236,
        resturant_name : "itrup",
        cusions : {1:"italian", 2: "american"},
        address : NYI

    }
]
```

I want to filter  array which has a cusions type 'american', from the the above object I am expecting response

```
   {
        id: 235,
        resturant_name : "kebab",
        cusions : {1:"china", 2 : "indian", 3: "american"},
        address : NYI

    },
    {
        id: 236,
        resturant_name : "itrup",
        cusions : {1:"italian", 2: "american"},
        address : NYI

    }
```

after filtration ^^^

Comment: right, what have you tried?

Comment: Is that supposed to be "cuisines"?

Comment: @Jordan yup it's the spelling mistake, as it  just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in combination with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for checking the wanted `cuisine`.

```js
var data = [{ id: 234, restaurant: "dish", cuisines: { 1: "italian", 2: "indian", 3: "foo" }, address: "NYI" }, { id: 235, restaurant: "kebab", cuisines: { 1: "china", 2: "indian", 3: "american" }, address: "NYI" }, { id: 236, restaurant: "itrup", cuisines: { 1: "italian", 2: "american" }, address: "NYI" }],
    cuisine = 'american',
    result = data.filter(function (a) {
        return Object.keys(a.cuisines).some(function (k) {
            return a.cuisines[k] === cuisine;
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6

```js
var data = [{ id: 234, restaurant: "dish", cuisines: { 1: "italian", 2: "indian", 3: "foo" }, address: "NYI" }, { id: 235, restaurant: "kebab", cuisines: { 1: "china", 2: "indian", 3: "american" }, address: "NYI" }, { id: 236, restaurant: "itrup", cuisines: { 1: "italian", 2: "american" }, address: "NYI" }],
    cuisine = 'american',
    result = data.filter(a => Object.values(a.cuisines).includes(cuisine));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to do:

```js
var arr = [
    {
    id: 234,
    resturant_name : "dish",
    cusions : {1:"italian", 2 : "indian", 3: "foo"},
    address : 'NYI'

    },
    {
        id: 235,
        resturant_name : "kebab",
        cusions : {1:"china", 2 : "indian", 3: "american"},
        address : 'NYI'

    },
    {
        id: 236,
        resturant_name : "itrup",
        cusions : {1:"italian", 2: "american"},
        address : 'NYI'

    }
];

var res = arr.filter(x=> {
 return JSON.stringify(x.cusions).indexOf('american') >=0;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: really a ternary for a boolean value?

Comment: @Nina Scholz Modified! Thanks!