# Filter observable by key

Tags: rxjs, observable

I am trying to filter a list of observables based on whether a parent key contains a specific child key. The parent key is Supplier, each Supplier has a list of child keys representing Users. The following code works, except that it returns every Supplier that contains any child User keys - not just Suppliers that contain the specific User key (FBKey).

I realise the current filter condition is a bit silly, but it is just where I am at after much fiddling and looking on the web.

```
userIsSupplierAdministrator(FBKey: number): Observable<Supplier[]> {
const suppliers$ = this.af.database.list('supplier-administrators');
return suppliers$
  .filter(supplier => !isUndefined(this.af.database.object(`suppliers/${supplier.$key}/${FBKey}`)))
  .map(supplier => supplier.map(supp => this.af.database.object(`suppliers/${supp.$key}`)))
  .flatMap(supplierObs => Observable.combineLatest(supplierObs))
  .map(Supplier.fromJsonList);
```

}

I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to structure the filter so that it only returns Suppliers that contain the specific child key (FFBKey).

I am using Angular/Typescript/Firebase.

Regards Sean

Comment: Thank you Sandeep the JSON suggestion helped me see what was going on much better. However I did not solve the issue. When I updated the filter to use JSON.stringify(supplier) the resulting

Comment: Thank you Sandeep the JSON suggestion helped me see what was going on much better. However I did not solve the issue. When I updated the filter to use JSON.stringify(supplier) the resulting object contained all the child keys from all suppliers? I was expecting the filter to act on each supplier independently, not to aggregate all the child keys.

Answer (score 1):

I request you to go through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666130/filter-the-value-in-object-when-the-keys-differ-in-an-array), you will able to solve your problem. 
The problem you have that is not related to the **observables** you are trying to fix the normal javascript problem.

The approach would be

1. get the json response from the observable
2. and filter the json using the below concepts

[Filter the value in object when the keys differ in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666130/filter-the-value-in-object-when-the-keys-differ-in-an-array)